# Prove that there exists a continuous increasing function $\sigma(x)$ on $I$ such that $\sigma'(x) = + \infty$ for every $x_0 \in E$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $I = [a, b], E \subset I, m(E) = 0$ (but $E$ not empty).  Prove that there exists a continuous increasing function $\sigma(x)$ on $I$ such that $\sigma'(x) = + \infty$ for every $x_0 \in E$.

I am having trouble with this question.  Any suggestions by chance?  Thanks.

Comment: Try the Cantor function.